# Seaborn Title Position

Tags: python, matplotlib, location, seaborn, title

The position of my graph title is terrible on this `jointplot`. I've tried moving the `loc = 'left`, `right`, and `center` but it doesn't move from the position it's in. I've also tried something like `ax.title.set_position([3, 15])` based on other suggestions from this site but that also doesn't move it at all. Any suggestions on controlling the location of the title?

```
sns.jointplot(leagueWinners_season['Wins'], leagueWinners_season['Goals'], kind = 'reg', color = 'b')
plt.title('Season Winners Goal and Win Regression', loc = 'right', fontsize = 16)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using

```
plt.title('Season Winners Goal and Win Regression', y=1.3, fontsize = 16)
```

where you can play around with the `y` position by changing the number. Here the position of `y` axis is in relative coordinate system which means `y=1` means at the highest `y` position in the plot and anything beyond 1 would mean pushing title further higher.

Comment: that's fantastic, worked perfectly. Do you happen to also know how to control the font size of the x and y labels ?

Answer (score 8):

Another way would be to use [`plt.suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html) to give a centered title to the figure, then use `subplots_adjust` to make slightly more room at the top of the figure for the title:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
plt.suptitle('Season Winners Goal and Win Regression', fontsize = 16)
```

Comment: That's interesting too, I just tried it out. I still can't believe how many different way there are to do the same thing. Thanks for the suggestions @DavidG