# set_title on seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Frustrating hour of trying to figure this out. Any idea how to show a title on a jointplot in seaborn?

```
title = "How long does it take to show a title with seaborn?"
g = sns.jointplot(x, y, space=0, color="b")
g.set_title = title
plt.show()
```

[image: The result]

Also tried:

```
plt.title = title


set_title(title))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add title to seaborn boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406233/how-to-add-title-to-seaborn-boxplot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.title` is a method, not an attibute, so:

```
plt.title(title)
```

works, but alignment of the title is not the best:

[image]

However, from [this question on seaborn title position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096050/seaborn-title-position)

I've combined the two answers (using `plt.suptitle` instead of `plt.title` and adding a y parameter) as:

```
title = "How long does it take to show a title with seaborn?"
g = sns.jointplot(x, y, space=0, color="b")
plt.suptitle(title, y = 1)
```

and got:

[image]

Comment: plt.title(title) gave the error 'str' object is not callable but plt.suptitle("hello", y =1) worked well enough. Thank you.

Comment: did you still have `plt.title = title` somewhere in your code by any chance ?

Comment: No but sure enough when I print(plt.title) it comes back as the title I've set. I guess I need to reset the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I can't control the location of the title. `plt.title('My title, loc='center')`  This was not enabled.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)

plt.title('My title')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the method to make it work

```
g.set_titles(title)
```